# The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
 var residenceRep = 
     ctx.ShiftEmployees
        .Include(s => s.UserData.NAME)
        .Include(s => s.ResidenceShift.shiftName)
        .Join(ctx.calc,
              sh => new { sh.empNum, sh.dayDate },
              o => new { empNum = o.emp_num, dayDate = o.trans_date },
              (sh, o) => new { sh, o })
        .Where(s => s.sh.recordId == recordId && s.o.day_flag.Contains("R1"))
        .OrderBy(r => r.sh.dayDate)
        .Select(r => new
             {
                  dayDate = r.sh.dayDate,
                  empNum = r.sh.empNum,
                  empName = r.sh.UserData.NAME,
                  shiftId = r.sh.shiftId,
                  shiftName = r.sh.ResidenceShift.shiftName,
                  recordId,
                  dayState = r.o.day_desc.Split('[', ']')[1]
             }).ToList();
```

---

I get an exception :

> The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities

How i could find an alternative to `Split('[', ']')[1]` in this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must commit the query and do the split after loading the data:

```
var residenceRep = 
 ctx.ShiftEmployees
    .Include(s => s.UserData.NAME)
    .Include(s => s.ResidenceShift.shiftName)
    .Join(ctx.calc,
          sh => new { sh.empNum, sh.dayDate },
          o => new { empNum = o.emp_num, dayDate = o.trans_date },
          (sh, o) => new { sh, o })
    .Where(s => s.sh.recordId == recordId && s.o.day_flag.Contains("R1"))
    .OrderBy(r => r.sh.dayDate)
    .Select(r => new
         {
              dayDate = r.sh.dayDate,
              empNum = r.sh.empNum,
              empName = r.sh.UserData.NAME,
              shiftId = r.sh.shiftId,
              shiftName = r.sh.ResidenceShift.shiftName,
              recordId = r.sh.recordId,
              dayState = r.o.day_desc,

         })
    .ToList()//Here we commit the query and load data
    .Select(x=> {
              var parts = x.dayState.Split('[', ']');
              return new {
                   x.dayDate,
                   x.empNum,
                   x.empName,
                   x.shiftId,
                   x.shiftName,
                   x.recordId,
                   dayState = parts.Length > 1 ?parts[1]:"",                 
             };
      })
      .ToList();
```

Comment: `Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.dayState' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Comment: I think it is the better practice to do `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()` since it doesn't fully iterate through the query-results. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had this Issue and the approach that I've chose was that get all element I wanted and **save** them into a **List** and then filter the actual data on that list.
I know **this is not the best answer** but it worked for me.